# Keyboard shortcut for Safari Address bar?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

What's the keyboard shortcut for the Safari address bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>CMD + L</kbd>

Also found by "Open Location..." under the File menu.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. My switch from Windows is now complete. :P

Comment: This should also work for other Mac browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Camino, etc.), assuming they're designed with any shred of common sense.

Comment: @Moshe missing ALT + D?